# UE5 C++ fatal error C1083: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

Unreal Engine 5.0.2 Visual Studio 2019
ProjectName: SandBox3

What I did:

Create a new C++ class named NewCharacter from SandBox3Character (default First Person template).

Live Coding Log:

```
Manual recompile triggered
---------- Creating patch ----------
Running E:\Editors\UE_5.0\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.exe -Target="SandBox3Editor Win64 Development -Project=""C:/Users/Uraking/Documents/Unreal_Projects/SandBox3/SandBox3.uproject""" -LiveCoding -LiveCodingModules="E:/Editors/UE_5.0/Engine/Intermediate/LiveCodingModules.txt" -LiveCodingManifest="E:/Editors/UE_5.0/Engine/Intermediate/LiveCoding.json" -WaitMutex -LiveCodingLimit=100
  Log file: C:\Users\Uraking\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log.txt
  Building SandBox3Editor...
  Using Visual Studio 2019 14.29.30145 toolchain (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133) and Windows 10.0.19041.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
  [Adaptive Build] Excluded from SandBox3 unity file: NewCharacter.cpp, SandBox3.cpp, SandBox3Character.cpp, SandBox3GameMode.cpp, SandBox3Projectile.cpp, TP_PickUpComponent.cpp, TP_WeaponComponent.cpp
  Determining max actions to execute in parallel (6 physical cores, 12 logical cores)
    Executing up to 6 processes, one per physical core
  Building 2 actions with 2 processes...
  [1/2] Compile NewCharacter.gen.cpp
  C:\Users\Uraking\Documents\Unreal_Projects\SandBox3\Source\SandBox3\Private\NewCharacter.h(6): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SandBox3Character.h': No such file or directory
  [2/2] Compile NewCharacter.cpp
  C:\Users\Uraking\Documents\Unreal_Projects\SandBox3\Source\SandBox3\Private\NewCharacter.h(6): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SandBox3Character.h': No such file or directory
Build failed.
```

But there is 'SandBox3Character.h' in parent directory.

[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w7LO.png)

How to can I solve this error?

Using DeepL to translate.

Comment: did you include with `<>` or `""`

Comment: Also according to the solution explorer the file you are including from is nested deeper, so did you make sure to use a relative include path (e.g.: `../SandBox3Character.h`)?

Comment: Relative includes are the devil. Just use the full path from content root.